# Why MSBuild is not working from batch file?

Tags: batch-file, msbuild, automation, command, bamboo

I am using `Bamboo` tool to build my `visual studio solution`. My MSbuild is in shared drive. I could able to access the network drive and could able to build the solution. But when I am passing the same command in a batch file. It is failing with an error as,

```
Line 1:    c:\Users\Desktop>\\NetworkPath\c$\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
           \MSBuild "\\Networkpath\Users\shareFolder\mi\Test\
Line 2:     MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Line 3:     Switch: \\PC181185\Users\shareFolder\Rasmi\Test\
Line 4:    c:\User\Desktop>TestProj\TestProj.sln"
```

The solution path is `"\\Networkpath\Users\shareFolder\mi\Test\TestProj\TestProj.sln"`
When I am passing them in command prompt as

```
c:\User\Desktop> \\NetworkPath\c$\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild "\\Networkpath\Users\shareFolder\mi\Test\TestProj\TestProj.sln"
```

This is working perfectly fine and builds the solution.

But when I am passing the same in batch file. It does not accepting the complete path.You can notice from `Line 1` and rest of the line repeats from `line 4`.

Please help me. How to resolve this problem.

Comment: Please post the content of the batch file exactly, probably you have a newline or something like that. There is nothing wrong with the command you show, so the problem is likely in the batch file..

Comment: @stijn: Thanks Sir, Yes I found a hidden new line character